# Deploy automático de projeto público para instância na AWS

Tags: github, amazon-aws, travis-ci

**Pergunta:**

Gostaria de saber como posso configurar o `Travis CI` para fazer o deploy automático de um projeto público do `GitHub` após executar o build e todos os testes passarem.

Reparei nessa configuração do arquivo `.travis.yml`, mas a dúvida que fica, informar os atributos `access_key_id` e o `secret_access_key` é mesmo seguro, como poderia fazer para configurar deploy automático de projetos públicos do GitHub?

```
/#http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: "" #YOUR ENCRYPTED AWS ACCESS KEY
  secret_access_key: "" #YOUR ENCRYPTED AWS SECRET KEY
  bucket: "make.stanleygeorge.com"
  skip_cleanup: true
  local-dir: out
on:
  tags: true
```

**Referências:**

[Setup Travis-CI for continuous integration](http://make.stanleygeorge.com/setup-travis-ci.html)

[S3 Deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/)

[AWS CodeDeploy](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/codedeploy/)

Comment: Você não consegue colocar esse projeto no bitbucket e fazer ele privado?

Comment: Consigo, mas a ideia era que fosse de código aberto

Comment: Então use variáveis de ambiente, assim cada um fica responsável por sua `access_key_id` e `secrect_access_key`

Comment: Não tenho acesso a máquina do TravisCI, ou tenho?